# No of Rows processed by cursor

Tags: oracle

```
declare
cid number;
cadd number;
ctras number;
pr varchar(2);
vad number;
cursor c1 IS
select ac_tras, cust_id, cust_addr from customer_master;
cursor c2 IS
select pr_adr from customer_address where cust_id = cid and cust_addr = cadd;
BEGIN
open c1;
LOOP
fetch c1 into ctras, cid, cadd;
EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
OPEN c2;
LOOP
fetch c2 into pr;
if pr='Y'
THEN EXIT ;
ELSE
UPDATE customer_master 
set cust_addr = (select cust_addr from customer_address where pr_adr = 'Y' and cust_id = cid) where ac_tras = ctras;
END IF;
EXIT WHEN C2%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
Close C2;
END LOOP;
CLOSE C1;
END;
```

Hi. In the above code, I need find the count of no of rows fetched. How to find it. In Other words, I have to find how many rows are processed or how many times the loops is iterated for Cursor C1

Comment: Or declare a counter variable and increment it inside the loop? Not sure if you want to count the loops separately, and/or count the number of rows actually updated. Why are you using nested loops instead of a join; and why are you using PL/SQL at all instead of a much simpler plain-SQL correlated update?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` to echo the amount of rows updated.
Example (paraphrasing your code to the relevant section, also adding a `COMMIT` for sanity):

```
...
UPDATE customer_master
SET cust_addr =
  (SELECT cust_addr FROM customer_address WHERE pr_adr = 'Y' AND cust_id = cid
  )
WHERE ac_tras = ctras;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Updated ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' records.');
...
```

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm)